# Introduction screens in Google Apps

Tags: android

I just bought a new phone and I noticed, opening for the first time Gmail and other G apps, some quite cool introduction screens.

I was wondering how this is implemented..

It doesn't look like just a simple ViewPager with fragments.
Could someone please give me an help?

I can't find any information online but those about ShowcaseView which is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I developed a library which does exactly that: https://github.com/rubengees/introduction

And yes, it is done with a ViewPager with Fragments, but with a fairly complex layout.
Another library I have found also does it with a Viewpager: https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro